# Common code for 2 process

Tags: java, jar

I have a project A for process A and project B for process B. These 2 different processes (but they communicate).
They share a common functionality on process startup and currently the code is duplicated.
I thought to create a common library for the common code and have this library part of the classpath of both projects.
Is this a good idea?

Comment: @Nim:The functionality is small.3-4 methods.I was wondering if it is too much hustle for nothing

Comment: it always starts out that way... then grows... why not start with a good design which encourages re-use from the start rather than refactoring later...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is good idea.

Also, in some cases, it could be good idea to run both processes with exactly the same classpath, but using different main classes, or even with the same main class, but with different command-line arguments.  This is especially handy when processes want to exchange serialized objects.